# PL/SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, table name not valid

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have to create a new table for each entry in a separate table(Studenti in my case) dynamically. I am just starting to learn about Dynamic Sql. I use the fallowing procedure:

```
    CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE carnet_student IS

  CREATE_TABLE_QUERY VARCHAR2(250);
  CURSOR table_name is SELECT NR_MATRICOL FROM STUDENTI;
  nume CHAR(4);
  BEGIN
    OPEN table_name;
    LOOP
      FETCH table_name INTO nume;
      EXIT when table_name%NOTFOUND;
      CREATE_TABLE_QUERY:='Create TABLE '||nume||'(
       column1 varchar2(50),
       column2 varchar2(50),
       column3 number(2),
       column4 DATE
       )';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CREATE_TABLE_QUERY;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE table_name;
  END;
  /

BEGIN
  carnet_student;
END;
```

I receive the error ORA-00903: invalid table name. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Did you create the STUDENTI table? It compiled for me.

Comment: A table name may not start with a number.

Comment: Ok, there is some problem

Comment: Studenti is created.

Comment: The column NR_Matricol from STUDENTI has char(4) as type, so I guess it can be used as a table name. The entries in that column are like this: '111' '112' etc

Comment: That's what a_horse_with_no_name said. Table name should not start with number. I am able to execute now. Had privilege issues earlier, which is not your root cause.

Comment: Ok thank you all, this was indeed the problem